# What is the preferred way to install a new Windows installation on an SSD with a Windows installation already on it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, installation, format

So I have an SSD right now(120 GB) with windows on it. I try to keep it clear from other things, but things have piled up over the years and now it's almost full.

I am building a new PC soon but I am keeping all my old drives, so since I have an OEM version of windows I need to get a new one and I am planning on installing it on the same SSD.

Now, am I correct in thinking that the new windows installation will simply format the SSD and write the new installation fresh on it? Or is there something else I have to do?

I'd rather not go through it and delete everything manually, also I need this SSD working until the very moment I plug it in to my new PC and install the new OS.

Sorry if I'm not making any sense, I don't know all the lingo. Feel free to ask if I'm bein unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am building a new PC soon but I am keeping all my old drives, so since I have an OEM version of windows I need to get a new one and I am planning on installing it on the same SSD.

Since you are indeed getting a new machine, all you have to do is boot into the installation media, and format the SSD that currently has Windows installed on it.  While you could choose NOT to format the drive before you install Windows, that would require a significant amount of space, that isn't likely to be available.

You will be unable to use your OEM license on your new machine, When prompted for the license key (unless it's an OEM license), you will have to enter a valid product key for Windows 10.  **This will only be the case the first time you install Windows 10 on the machine.**

> Now, am I correct in thinking that the new windows installation will simply format the SSD and write the new installation fresh on it? Or is there something else I have to do?

All you have to do is choose the format option within the Windows installation environment.

> I'd rather not go through it and delete everything manually, also I need this SSD working until the very moment I plug it into my new PC and install the new OS.

There is a button to delete partitions.  All you have to do is select each partition and delete it.  You should backup your data before you delete the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is just to boot to the installation media (USB key or, less likely, disk) and during the installation delete the existing partitions.

It's that simple.

Comment: I've found out that windows doesn't actually like to do this and instead makes a backup in a windows.old directory which is then a PITA to remove, despite asking it to wipe/format the drive

Comment: If you get a Windows.old folder that means you didn't do what I instructed. If you booted to the installer (not running it from inside Windows) and deleted the partitions, there would be no data left on the drive at all.