# Does cloning Windows 10 to a larger SSD require activation?

Tags: windows-activation, clonezilla

I am planning to buy a Windows-10 desktop and will clone an image file of the Windows-10 drive: possibly for future use in larger SSD.  When the Clonezilla file is imaged to a larger SSD, should I expect to be required to activate Windows-10?  Assume that the larger SSD is the only variable that is changed.

Comment: I have never had to re-activate after a clone, it is usually a motherboard change that triggers it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the preferred way to install a new Windows installation on an SSD with a Windows installation already on it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1484720/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-install-a-new-windows-installation-on-an-ssd-with-a)

Comment: You will not have to activate Windows again.

Answer (score 3):

Just transferring from one hard drive or SSD to another is not enough to invalidate your activation. I have done this a few times without issue.

Changing the motherboard or making significant changes will invalidate it requiring reactivation.

[Reactivating Windows 10 after a hardware change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change)

Comment: Even if it *did* trigger reactivation, changing a hard disk doesn't constitute moving the Windows license to a new computer (whereas getting a new motherboard does if it's not an identical model) so there will be no trouble reactivating after the upgrade.